# Programmatically highlight a stringgrid row

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tstringgrid

i have a string grid in Delphi 7, with 0..N rows. There is a listbox with numbers from 0..N
if the user clicks on the any number in the listbox number , that row number should be selected on the stringgrid.

so i have this

```
   MystringGrid.Col :=0;
   MystringGrid.Row :=Listbox.itemindex;
   MystringGrid.Selection:=TGridRect(Rect(0,1 ,1 ,1));
   MystringGrid.SetFocus;
```

This will nicely select the row on the grid (highlight it) but the problem is if

```
 listbox.itemindex=MystringGrid.rowcount;
```

That time i get

```
 Grid Index out of range error
```

as in grids.pas

```
 if (ACol < 0) or (ARow < 0) or (ACol >= ColCount) or (ARow >= RowCount) then
  InvalidOp(SIndexOutOfRange)
```

`(ARow >= RowCount)` is true so error

how do i select the last row?

Comment: Off by one or fencepost errors, as we call them, are a PEBKAC problem. Problem exists between keyboard and chair. I.E., your human brain is off by one, not the computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are `3` rows, then they are called

```
0,  1,  2.
```

Notice that there is no row called `3`.

More generally, if there are `N` rows, then they are called

```
0,  1,  2, ..., N - 1.
```

Notice that there is no row called `N`.

Hence, your problem can be found already on the first line of your question:

> i [sic!] have a string grid in Delphi 7, with N rows. There is a listbox with
>   numbers from 0..N

If there are `N` rows, then the listbox should contain the numbers `0..N-1`. Indeed, if you let it contain the numbers `0..N`, then the number of lines in the listbox will equal `N+1`, i.e., one more than the number of items in the string grid.

Also: I'd do simply

```
StringGrid1.Selection := TGridRect(Rect(0, 3, 4, 3))
```

to select the row with index `3`, assuming the number of columns is `4+1`

Comment: (i changed 0..n in question ) ok thats correct :)..but the thing is if i select 1 in the listbox..the 1st row is selected. The listbox and the grid has equal number of rows. the only problem is for the last row when i click on the last row of the listbox, the grid index out of range error comes as grids.pas raise error

Comment: @psqluser: Your selection code is weird, too. I'd do simply `StringGrid1.Selection := TGridRect(Rect(0, 3, 4, 3))` to select the row with index `3`, assuming the number of columns is `4+1`.